# Prove that if $f=f'$ then $f$ is monotone.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I do not know that $e^x$ solves the equation $$f'(x)=f(x),\;\;\;x\in\mathbb{R}.$$ I am just given this equation and want to see if $f$ is increasing. Is there a way to prove that $f$ is increasing without going through power series (with all theorems it requires) and redefinig the exponential function?

**EDIT 1**

I meant monotone not increasing.

Comment: $-e^x$ is not increasing.

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1292586/72031

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer for the earlier version of the question: $f(x)=-e^{x}$ also satisfies this property so $f$ need not be increasing.

PS $f^{2}$ has derivative $2ff'=2f^{2} \geq 0$ so $f^{2}$ is increasing. It follows that $f$ is monotonic (see for example [If $f^2$ monotonically increasing in $R$ then f monotonic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019579/if-f2-monotonically-increasing-in-r-then-f-monotonic)).

Comment: You've been just 2 seconds earlier ...

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: That is a truly elegant argument! The final conclusion ($f^2$ increasing implies that $f$ is monotone) is nicely demonstrated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1019970/42969).

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much for that reference.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to add the reference to your answer. Comments are ephemeral and can be deleted at any time.

Comment: @MartinR You did the right thing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Assume that $f'$ has not the same sign everywhere, i.e. $f'(x_1) > 0$ and $f'(x_2) < 0$.

If $x_1 < x_2$ then $f$ attains its maximum on $[x_1, x_2]$ at a point $x_3$ in the open interval $(x_1, x_2)$.  Then $f(x_3) \ge f(x_1) = f'(x_1) > 0$, but $f'(x_3) = 0$.

If $x_2 < x_1$ then the same argument is used with the minimum on $[x_2, x_1]$, giving also a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see $f_0(x) = 0$ is a fixed point of the derivative, so if $f(x)$ satisfies $f'(x) = f(x)$ and $f(0) > 0,$ then $f'(x) = f(x) > 0$ for all $x$.  Similarly, if $f(0) < 0$, then $f'(x) = f(x) < 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich What's your question?

Comment: How does $f_0'=f_0$ imply what you say it does?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Using the "uniqueness theorem," solutions to $f' = f$ cannot intersect, so a solution that is $f > f_0$ at a point is also $f > f_0$ for all points.

Comment: Fine. I realized it followed from uniqueness for DE's, decided not to post an answer because the OP wanted something "easy". Didn't realize that's what you meant here.

Comment: It's definitely not an argument from first principles, which is why I'm fine with the other answers being rated higher, but it's an argument that can be made without any knowledge of the nontrivial solutions, which I believe was the only request.

Answer (score 1):

One can prove that if such a function vanishes once it vanishes everywhere.

If $f(a) =0$ then we prove that $f(x) =0$ for all $x$. Suppose there is a $b\neq a$ with $f(b) \neq 0$ and then let $F(x) =f(b-a+x) f(a+b-x) $. Clearly $$F'(x) = f'(b-a+x) f(a+b-x) - f(b-a+x) f'(a+b-x) =0$$ (via $f'=f$) and hence $F$ is constant. Then $F(x) =F(a)=f(b)f(b)>0$ and $F(b) =f(2b-a)f(a)=0$ and we have a contradiction.

Thus one option is that $f(x) =0$ for all $x$ and another option is that $f$ does not vanish anywhere. By continuity $f$ maintains a constant sign and $f'=f$ shows that $f$ is strictly monotone.